# Unable to load class net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeIntegrationUnavailableException

Tags: android-studio, developer-tools

I just installed Android Studio, created my first project and got this message: "Unable to load class net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeIntegrationUnavailableException".

I asked my tutor for help, he said I don't have Java installed, but I have it installed: my Kotlin projects compile. The version of the SDK I have is 33. Can you please tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: I tried to open the Telegram code and got this error: Unable to load class 'com.google.common.util.concurrent.internal.InternalFutureFailureAccess'.

This is an unexpected error. Please file a bug containing the idea.log file.

Comment: @laymelek Unfortunately, no. Try to remove non-ASCII characters from the project path and SDK, if any, or just reinstall the SDK. Please write, if any of this helps

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who still has this problem after restarting Android Studio, or after clearing the Android Studio cache, here is a definite fix.

This error does sometimes seem to pop up when there is a SDK update in Android Studio. To fix this, go to the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file, and update the `distributionUrl` as such:

1. Go to the following URL: https://services.gradle.org/distributions/
2. Check the latest version of the gradle distributable. Look at the top most files for the latest version number. At the time of writing this answer, 8.6 is the latest version.
3. Go back to your `gradle-wrapper.properties` file and edit the `distributionUrl` by replacing the existing version with the latest version that you found in step 2. Here is an example:

*Old version*: `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.2-bin.zip` 
*Replace with*:
`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.6-bin.zip`

4. Sync gradle after doing the changes. Your IDE should prompt you automatically to do so.